# if a useState holds a string, does setting it to an identical string trigger downstream dependencies?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-state

```
const [stuff, set_stuff] = useState("a")


...

set_stuff("a")
```

when `set_stuff("a")` is run, will it trigger downstream?

Comment: The [`useState` documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usestate) doesn't explicitly say so in the case of a direct update like `set_stuff("a")`, but it *does* say of functional updates (`set_stuff(() => "a")`): *"If your update function returns the exact same value as the current state, the subsequent rerender will be skipped completely."* That supports the impirical result that no, calling `set_stuff` with the exact same value will not cause a re-render.

Comment: Definitively, no, the component doesn't rerender: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-gmgohl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [the documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#bailing-out-of-a-state-update) (of which another part was cited in the comments),

> If you update a State Hook to the same value as the current state, React will bail out without rendering the children or firing effects.   (React uses the [`Object.is` comparison algorithm](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/is#Description).)

which means that no, setting the state to the same value it had should not trigger a re-render or re-computing any dependents; `set_stuff(stuff)` should generally be a no-op.  Of course, a re-render may trigger at the same time for unrelated reasons.

Also, remember that `Object.is` compares objects by identity (so-called ‘shallow’ equality), which means updating the state to an object with the same properties as the old one will not be considered identical and will trigger a re-render, even if the programmer considers the new state equivalent.